# Have /bin/bash not /usr/bin/bash, but can't install RPM update because of failed dependency

Tags: upgrade, rpm, dependencies

Linux system with bash located in `/bin` and not `/usr/bin`.

Attempting to install (as root) `glibc-common-2.17-222.el7.x86_64` using either of the following commands:

```
rpm -ivh glibc-2.17-222.el7.x86_64.rpm glibc-common-2.17-222.el7.x86_64.rpm
```

or

```
yum localinstall glibc-common-2.17-222.el7.x86_64.rpm glibc-2.17-222.el7.x86_64.rpm
```

Get a dependency error:
`/usr/bin/bash is needed by glibc-common-2.17-222.el7.x86_64`

```
[root@ruapp117 dep]# ls -ld /bin
dr-xr-xr-x. 2 root root 4096 Mar  5  2018 /bin

[root@ruapp117 dep]# rpm -q --whatprovides /bin/bash /usr/bin/bash
bash-4.1.2-48.el6.x86_64
error: file /usr/bin/bash: No such file or directory

[root@smbruapp117 dep]# rpm -qa | grep bash
bash-4.1.2-48.el6.x86_64
```

Connectivity to the internet is not possible; I am having to manually download and install.

Answer (score 2):

Since that's the only issue preventing the installation, and you're sure that you have bash installed, tell RPM to skip dependency-checking:

```
rpm -ivh --nodeps glibc-2.17-222.el7.x86_64.rpm glibc-common-2.17-222.el7.x86_64.rpm
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to install a centos package on another os?

The package you are trying to install depends on /bin/bash. The question is why, and/or why /bin/bash is not on your machine.

So maybe the packager hardcoded the dependency on /bin/bash, then there is not much you can do except rebuilding the src.rpm and changing the spec file, or force installing (rpm --nodeps) and creating a symlink so everything works.

When rpm builds a package, it automatically searches for its dependencies, so maybe it was rpmbuild that added the dependency, maybe because the machine on which the rpm was built had /bin/bash and not /usr/bin/bash. In that case you can try searching another version of this package that was not built on centos (without the 'el7' part) and try installing that.

These are some thoughts that should help you quite a lot on the way.